# filter arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have filter arrays and need to fetch items which have these filters in the item .fruit and veg filters and I need to get the items which have both filters. What is the best way to filter items?

```
fruitfilter: [] = [{fruitname: "apple"} , {fruitname:"orange"}]
vegetablefilter: [] = [{vegetablename:"tomato"}, {vegetablename:"potato"}]

items: [] = [{fruitname: "apple", vegetablename:"tomato"},
                     {fruitname: "melon", vegetablename:"onion"},
                     {fruitname: "banana", vegetablename:"onion"}]
result: [] = [{fruitname: "apple", vegetablename:"tomato"}]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: This platform is for helping you after you have tried your best. So, please try to solve it on your own and post question if you are getting stuck.

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı, I tried one solution in which first filter fruits and then veg but some times these filters can be empty. not sure how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this:

```js
const fruitfilter=[{fruitname:"apple"},{fruitname:"orange"}],
      vegetablefilter=[{vegetablename:"tomato"},{vegetablename:"potato"}],
      items=[{fruitname:"apple",vegetablename:"tomato"},{fruitname:"melon",vegetablename:"onion"},{fruitname:"banana",vegetablename:"onion"}];

const result = 
  items.filter(i => fruitfilter.some(f => f.fruitname === i.fruitname)
                     && vegetablefilter.some(v => v.vegetablename === i.vegetablename))

console.log(result)
```

If the filters can be empty, you can check if they are empty using `length`

```
const result = 
  items.filter(i => (!fruitfilter.length || fruitfilter.some(f => f.fruitname === i.fruitname))
                     && (!vegetablefilter.length || vegetablefilter.some(v => v.vegetablename === i.vegetablename)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This solution is not working when one of the filters is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just check with `includes`. You will need to change the data types slightly for comparison on an array of objects - that's what `fruit` and `vegitable` are for:

```js
const fruitfilter = [{fruitname: "apple"} , {fruitname:"orange"}];
const vegitablefilter = [{vegitablename:"tomato"}, {vegitablename:"potato"}];
const items = [{fruitname: "apple", vegitablename:"tomato"},{fruitname: "melon", vegitablename:"onion"},{fruitname: "banana", vegitablename:"onion"}];
const fruit = fruitfilter.map(({ fruitname }) => fruitname);
const vegitable = vegitablefilter.map(({ vegitablename }) => vegitablename);
const result = items.filter(item => item.fruitname ? fruit.includes(item.fruitname) : vegitable.includes(item.vegitablename));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am getting the empty array when one of the filter arrays is empty.